# OOP air conditioner model

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, interview-questions, ecmascript-6

I had a phone interview and we shared a screen to do a simple challenge. Instructions were ambiguous but I basically had to implement how an air conditioner would work in general. I wrote the following as I talked it out with the interviewer.

So I made a class with a parameter that would be a room temp and then added two properties, `heatingSystem` and `coolingSystem` and set them as booleans. Then wrote a function called `setTemperature` that should’ve been a while loop that changes the temperature and setting of the A/C until it reaches the set temperature.

```
class AirConditioner {
   constructor(temperature) {
       this.temperature = temperature;
       this.coolingSystem = false;
       this.heatingSystem = false;
   }



  temperatureSet(temperature) {
    while (this.temperature != temperature) {
       if (this.temperature < temperature) {
           // turn on the cooling system and turn off heating system
           if (this.coolingSystem) {
               this.coolingSystem = false;
               this.heatingSystem = true;
               this.temperature++;
           } else {
             this.heatingSystem = true;
             console.log('Temperature has been lowered to ' + this.temperature);
             this.temperature++;
           }
       } else if (this.temperature > temperature) {
           // turn off the cooling system and turning the heating
           if (this.heatingSystem) {
               this.coolingSystem = true;
               this.heatingSystem = false;
               console.log('Temperature has been increased to ' + this.temperature);
               this.temperature--;
           } else {
             this.coolSystem = true;
             console.log('Temperature has been lowered to ' + this.temperature);
             this.temperature--;
           }
       } else {
           // turn off cooling/heating system but keep the fan un
           console.log('temp is the same')
       }
    }
      console.log(`this.temperature: ${this.temperature} temperature: ${temperature}`)
  }
}

const AC = new AirConditioner(78);
console.log(AC);
AC.temperatureSet(63);
console.log(AC);
```

I honestly don't like the code and can already see a lot of possibilities on how to refactor or add other functions for re-usability. I was wondering what your suggestions are.

Comment: Was it a requirement for the interview that you use OOP?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the position you were interviewed for. Below is the embedded engineer point of view.

- A room temp is *not* a class parameter. The AC cannot control it directly, so `this.temperature++` and `this.temperature--` are incorrect. The AC may only read the temp sensor.
- The *desired* temperature OTOH *is* a class parameter. You should go an extra mile and provide the interface to set it. BTW, I'd expect `temperatureSet` to do just that: set the desired temperature.
- As implemented, the program terminates as soon as a certain temperature is reached. I expect an AC system to run more or less forever.
- In the `if (this.temperature < temperature)` clause you turn on heater no matter what. Move the `this.heatingSystem = true;` line outside of `this.coolingSystem` clause.

Assuming the above recommendations are implemented, the basic functionality should look like this:

```
    while(true) {
        ambientTemperature = this.temperatureSensor.read();
        if (ambientTemperature < this.targetTemperature) {
            if (this.coolingSystem) {
                this.coolingSystem = false;
            } else {
                console.log('Temperature has been lowered to ' + ambientTemperature);
            }
            this.heatingSystem = true;
        } else {
        ....
```

Of course there is a plenty of room to improve, but again that depends on interviewer expectations, and the AC schematics you'd agree upon.

Comment: I really like the way you did this answer, tying it directly to the HVAC.

Comment: Given the nature of having to switch off the `cooling` boolean when the `heating` boolean is enabled, it might be better to simply use an int with 3 states so you don't have to set two values at the same time (and risk going out of sync when you make a mistake). Or, alternatively, calculate `needsHeating` and `needsCooling` on the fly (by comparing the temperatures)